# Mongo aggregate works in local but not in production

Tags: php, mongodb

In local enviroment I use Windows, PHP 5.5.0 and lastest version of MongoDB and MongoDB Driver. In produccion I use: Cent OS 6, and all the same.

My code is:

```
    $result = $mongodb->messages->aggregate(
    ['$match' =>
        ['$or' =>
            [
                array('from_group'   => $hangoutA),
                array('from_group'   => $hangoutB),
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [ '$group' => [
        '_id' => null,
        'message' => ['$last' => '$message'],
        'sent_time' => ['$last' => '$sent_time']
    ]
    ]);
```

This code works in local, but not in production.

Returns: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /var/www/html/app/models/Messages.php on line 43`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I don't have the same PHP version in production. You need PHP 5.4+ to use `([])` in PHP.

Update your PHP version, that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well aggregate expects it's pipeline parameter as a list, so I would suggest wrapping the statement with `[ .. ]` as below:

```
$result = $mongodb->messages->aggregate([
    ['$match' =>
        ['$or' =>
            [
                array('from_group'   => $hangoutA),
                array('from_group'   => $hangoutB),
            ]
        ]

    ],
    [ '$group' => [
        '_id' => null,
        'message' => ['$last' => '$message'],
        'sent_time' => ['$last' => '$sent_time']
    ]]

]);
```

Comment: At least in the current driver version, it supports either way. http://us1.php.net/mongocollection.aggregate

Comment: @WiredPrairie And word to mr mikola on that. The general preference I see is to do something that would "serialize" to JSON and round-trip the same. That makes the syntax valid for everyone. Which I guess what kind of the point.

Comment: Personal preference I guess. The syntax also mirrors the console's support for aggregation. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate

Comment: @WiredPrairie Well mine does. I'm yet to figure if this was an exercise in self answering. Albeit in the wrong way, and as noted **did not** share the correct solution, away from the obvious that we would have suggested. So I therefore say, not personal, but correct.